# MVC Control.Visible

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, show-hide

i'm new in mvc and i want to show/hide a html control after a jquery ajax call. 

 In ASP.NET is simple like set Label.Visible = false.

i have a razor view with something like this:

```
    @if (ViewBag.Show)
    {
        Html.Label("Test");
    }

    <input id="idClick" type="button" value="Click"/>
```

and a script with jquery to call an action

```
    $("#idClick").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/Test/ShowLabel',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                    }
                });
```

In my index view i set:

```
    ViewBag.Show = false;
```

in the action:

```
    public void ShowLabel()
    {
        ViewBag.Show = true;
    }
```

but i can't get the label showed

i want to avoid render the control and then apply a style to hide it

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the following code is also on said "index view":

```
@if (ViewBag.Show)
{
    Html.Label("Test");
}
```

If that is the case, you are overwriting `ViewBag.Show` in the index view when you use `ViewBag.Show = false;`.  Remove that line and it will show your textbox.

**Edit**

I just noticed your "action" is returning void--meaning no view will get rendered if this action method gets called.  It seems you need to read up more on how ASP.NET MVC works, or rephrase your question.

If you do not set `ViewBag.Show = true;` in the index action method (or whichever one is being used to create your view) then ViewBag.Show will default to false.  Ensure you are setting the variable where it is actually being called and don't overwrite it in your view.

**Edit 2**

In response to your edit, do not use the `ViewBag` at all to hide your controls.  Instead, just pass in an anonymous type to the HTML helper:

```
Html.Label("Test", new { style = "display: none;" })
```

or use a CSS class instead:

```
Html.Label("Test", new { @class = "some-class-with-display-none" })
```

**Edit 3**

Your question is really hard to follow and I see that you were trying to use Ajax to send back the `ViewBag` to the page.  You can't do this.  The `ViewBag` is a server-side only "bag" that is only used to initially render the page.  You can either return Json/Xml from your action method to indicate if the label should be hidden or visible, or use a partial page update.

I think based on the amount of scattered information you have, it might be wise to start with synchronous pages first, and get a feel for how ASP.NET MVC works before tossing in Ajax calls.

**Edit 4**

It seems that you want to be able to change the visibility of your label based on the results of an Ajax call. Since `ViewBag` is not going to change a thing when your user already has the page rendered, you need to return the result back to your page via JSON, XML, or a partial page refresh.  The simplest would be to return some JSON:

```
public JsonResult ShowLabel ()
{
    return Json (new { result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then add an ID to your label:

```
<label id="testLabel" style="display: none">Test</label>
```

And then make your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Test/ShowLabel'
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
}).success(function (d) {
    if (d.result) {
        $('#testLabel').show();
    }
});
```

**Final Edit**

Since I see you want this for validation, you can save yourself a lot of headache and use the built-in mechanisms with [Remote Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. from your second answer, the label is rendered but not shown and i want to know if is there a way to render tne label only after going to my model and passing some validation. but not change the style to shown the label

Comment: @Charly - Your question is really confusing.  Are you going to pass some validation to your `ShowLabel` action method and then display the label based on the results?  (Basically, a Boolean value would hide or show it?)

Comment: i'm sorry, yes exactly what you said (i'm going to pass some validation to my ShowLabel action method and then display the label based on the results)

Comment: @Charly - So then you need something like my Edit 4?

Comment: in some way but when i request the page, the label is redered but not shown until passing the validation and i'm wondering if is there a way to render the label only after passing the validation.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. It is hidden *until* the Ajax call comes back and calls `.show()`.  What more do you need?  If you need the steps reversed, remove the CSS to hide the label and call `.hide()` instead.

Comment: for example in ASP.NET when you click a button in the event you could set Label.Visible = false. On the page if you go to View Source you can't see the definition for the label, but with mvc i got to the view source and a can see de definition <label for="Test" style="display: none;">Test</label>

Comment: That is a different question altogether than what you asked. It is a fundamental difference between WebForms and MVC. You can inject the label into the DOM if you don't want it to appear in the markup. Otherwise, you have a lot of reading to do.

Comment: so, instead of this $('#testLabel').show(); i need to create the label dinamically?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without setting anything in `ViewBag`)

**Note:**
If the ajax call is only for setting the visibility of label, you can safely get rid of the ajax call.

```
 <label for="Test" style="display:none;"></label>

 $("#idClick").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/Test/ShowLabel',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                    }
                });
     $("label[for='Test']").css("display", "block")
  });
```

Comment: Why make the ajax call at all if you're not going to use the result? (Especially when one isn't being returned in this instance.)

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo yes agreed...I have kept the ajax call just in case OP want to set some other elements using ajax.

Comment: because i want to show more controls like buttons, etc.. and i want to avoid render all the controls. supose i hide a button,i could write something like $("#test").show() when debbuging because  the button was rendered;